# How do I "replay" the "Caveats" section from a homebrew recipe

Tags: macos, homebrew

When installing a homebrew recipe, you occasionally will get some useful information in the "Caveats" section that you may want to tuck under your hat. Is there any way to replay or access this information once it has been displayed at install or is it lost forever unless you copy paste somewhere?

e.g.

```
==> Caveats
To have launchd start mongodb at login:
    ln -s /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
Then to load mongodb now:
    launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    mongod
```

I might want to be able to see this again and/or know where that plist is if I want it later.

**tl;dr** How do I see the above snippet again after I've installed something from homebrew?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`brew info mongodb` will display it. If you make the changes suggested by the Caveats however, there may be other Caveats presented which will be more applicable to your actual situation.

Answer (score 19):

I created a brew external command for that: https://github.com/rafaelgarrido/homebrew-caveats

```
$ brew caveats zsh
==> zsh: Caveats
Add the following to your zshrc to access the online help:
    unalias run-help
    autoload run-help
    HELPDIR=/usr/local/share/zsh/helpfiles
```

You can also pass multiple formulas:

```
$ brew caveats rabbitmq mongodb
==> rabbitmq: Caveats
Management Plugin enabled by default at http://localhost:15672

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d

To have launchd start rabbitmq at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/rabbitmq/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load rabbitmq now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  rabbitmq-server

==> mongodb: Caveats
To have launchd start mongodb at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mongodb now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
  mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Pretty handy when you need to check some configs!

Comment: `brew caveats $(brew list)` shows caveats of all installed packages

Answer (score 10):

To see all caveats of the currently installed formulas you can use the following command

```
brew info $(brew list)
```

You can also filter the output with awk to only get the caveats sections. (I am an awk newbie suggestions or edits are welcome)

```
brew info $(brew list) | awk '/^==> Caveats$/,/^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_+-]+: stable |^==> (Dependencies|Options)$/'
```

Comment: Avoid command substitution for long lists. Pipe through `xargs` where possible.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use sed

```
brew info $(brew list) | sed '/==> Caveats/,/==>/!d;//d'
```

And to have a formatted output (bash)

```
for cmd in $(brew list); do 
  if brew info $cmd | grep -q Caveats; then
    echo "$cmd\n"; 
    brew info $cmd | sed '/==> Caveats/,/==>/!d;//d'; 
    printf '%40s\n' | tr ' ' -; 
  fi; 
done;
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who have the awesome `jq` tool:

```sh
# For brews
$ brew list --formula | xargs brew info --json | jq -r '.[] | select(.caveats != null) | "\n\nName: \(.name)\nCaveats: \(.caveats)"'

# For casks
$ brew list --cask | xargs brew info --cask --json=v2 | jq -r '.casks[] | select(.caveats != null) | "\n\nName: \(.name)\nCaveats: \(.caveats)"'
```

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a command-line JSON processor.

Answer (score 0):

Updating and combining a few above anwers, here's a bash/zsh loop that can be pasted into the terminal to get all caveats for all installed brew formulae.

```
for x in $(brew list --formula); do 
    cavs=$(brew info "$x" | sed '/==> Caveats/,/==>/!d;//d')
    if [ ! -z "$cavs" ]; then
        echo "$x"
        echo "---"
        echo "$cavs"
        echo ""
    fi
done
```