# How to have brew give post-install instructions?

Tags: homebrew

I want to see the instructions brew gives for starting postgres, however it is already installed. It showed these instructions after installation.

What's the command to just view post-install instructions again with brew on a Mac?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I "replay" the "Caveats" section from a homebrew recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333585/how-do-i-replay-the-caveats-section-from-a-homebrew-recipe)

Answer (score 17):

The command:

```
brew info postgresql
```

gives:

```
postgresql: stable 9.4.2 (bottled)
https://www.postgresql.org/
Conflicts with: postgres-xc
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.2 (3004 files, 40M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔, readline ✔
==> Options
--32-bit
    Build 32-bit only
--with-dtrace
    Build with DTrace support
--with-python
    Build with python support
--without-perl
    Build without Perl support
--without-tcl
    Build without Tcl support
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.4) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/upgrading.html

To have launchd start postgresql at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load postgresql now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```